# Shampoo cycle loop

Tags: python

I am having trouble figuring out how to stop the loop in my code:

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    for num_cycles in range(1,num_cycles+1):
        if num_cycles < 1:
            print 'Too few.'
        elif num_cycles > 4:
            print 'Too many.' 
        else:
            print num_cycles, ': Lather and rinse.'
    else:     
        print 'Done.'

shampoo_instructions(2)
```

My output would be:

> > 1 : Lather and rinse.
> >
> > 2 : Lather and rinse.
> >
> > Done.

How can i make it so when shampoo_instructions(6)

it just prints "Too many."

?

Comment: You're doing your range checking inside your `range` - put it outside the `range`, then you know it's safe to use your `range`...

Comment: Q. How did the programmer die in the shower? A. He read the shampoo bottle instructions: Lather. Rinse. Repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your range check to be outside your actual looping, eg:

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print 'Too few.'
    elif num_cyles > 4:
        print 'Too many.'
    else:
        for num_cycles in range(1,num_cycles+1):
            print num_cycles, 'lather and rinse.'
        print 'Done'
```

Comment: probably better not to use `num_cycles` in the loop

Comment: @Padraic in this case, being immutable and of limited scope, it doesn't actually matter, but it's a good point... if the original `num_cycles` value needs to be retained then yes, the OP should definitely rename `num_cycles` in the for loop - good spot :)

Comment: Only spotted it because  I got strange behaviour using break in the loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

found some help from reddit.

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles <= 0:
        print("Too few.")
    elif num_cycles >= 5:
        print("Too many.")
    else:
        for num_cycles in range (1, num_cycles + 1):
            print(num_cycles,":", "Lather and rinse.")
        print("Done.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
''' Your solution goes here '''
def print_shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 1
        while i <= num_cycles:
            print(f'{i} : Lather and rinse.')
            i += 1
        print('Done.')

user_cycles = int(input())
print_shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_shampoo_instructions(user_cycles):
    if user_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
    elif user_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
    else:
        for user_cycles in range (1, user_cycles + 1):
            print(f'{user_cycles}: Lather and rinse.')
        print("Done.")
```

user_cycles = int(input())
print_shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)